# 301 .htaccess redirects with two separate URLs

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to URL redirect to both

```
example.com/new-old.php
```

and

```
example.com/new-feb.php
```

when the user goes to

example.com/new

How do I do it?

Comment: Fixed formatting & clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this 301 rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(new)-(old|feb)/?$ /$1
```